# Programmatically login to google app engine c#

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I've tried to login to my google app engine application from ASP.NET for a few days, but no luck. I've read the following articles and got the basic ideas. But nothing works for me.
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577217-routines-for-programmatically-authenticating-with-/ 
http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=303
http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=894
http://krasserm.blogspot.com/2010/01/accessing-security-enabled-google-app.html 
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

I know what to do. 1) Get an auth token from ClientLogin. 2) Get a cookie from Google App Engine. 3) Post data to my app with the cookie (Yes, I want to post data, not redirect after the second part). But the third part doesn't work for me at all. It give me 403 error. Here is my code:

```
void PostToGAE()
{
    var auth = GetAuth();  // I can get the authtoken
    var cookies = GetCookies(auth);  // I can get the ACSID cookie

    var url = string.Format("http://test.appspot.com/do/something/");
    var content = "testvalue=test";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // This gives me 403
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}

CookieContainer GetCookies(string auth)
{
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    var url = string.Format("http://test.appspot.com/_ah/login?auth={0}",
                            System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(auth));
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    reader.Close();
    return cookies;
}

string GetAuth()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    var content = "Email=test@gmail.com&Passwd=testpass&service=ah&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string loginStuff = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    var auth = loginStuff.Substring(loginStuff.IndexOf("Auth")).Replace("Auth=", "").TrimEnd('\n');
    return auth;
}
```

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
- url: /do/something/
  script: something.py
  login: admin
```

If I change the method POST to GET, that works. Could anyone tell me how I can post data?
Thanks.

EDITED:
Still no luck. I've tried several ways such as changing to [login: required] in app.yaml, adding [secure: always] to app.yaml and changing the request protocol to https, appending continue parameter to /_ah/login, but all of them don't work :(
I totally have no idea why POST doesn't work at all but GET. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it. I was on the wrong track. That was not the problem of app engine but Django. I am using Django-nonrel on google app engine, and I totally forgot to put **@csrf_exempt** decorator to my handler. I had the same problem before, but again. Anyway, the code above has been apparently working correctly since at the beginning. What a smart boy :)